login/authenticator Catch-22 with Heroku
I am a somewhat technical non-developer doing the admin work to keep a deployed Chrome extension working OK for its users until I find another developer to do more work on the product.  The deployment uses Heroku, and that site has notified me that they will delete my account if I do not login to it.  I try to login but it asks me to authenticate using my authenticator app—the login screen says “To keep your account secure, we verify your identity.Enter the code generated by your authenticator app.”  But I think I mistakenly deleted the Google Authenticator app months ago.
I have sent an email to support@heroku.com but have received no response in 3 days.  The deadline they gave me is in another 3-4 days.
I need help getting out of this dilemma.
Any suggestions would be appreciated!

The only ones that would be able to do anything is Heroku themselves, not Stack Overflow; we can't provide customer support for companies. The best you can do is attempt to find your recovery codes, or reinstall your authenticator app on the same device in the hopes that the files containing the keys are still on your phone.

Yes, Heroku has still not responded, and my recovery codes are not available, period.  Oh well.
